# How to get data out of a Table element which isn't a member of another table

Tags: java, arrays

I have a problem with a table in JAVA.
So I want to know, how do I get all the data out of a table1 which isn't a member of table2.

Example : table1 [1, 2, 3, 4] , table2[1, 2, 3]

I want to get the data "4" out of table1.

If someone can help me, please do.

Comment: Are these "tables" really arrays, or something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically you will want to search one array for each element in the other array and see if you find the element. If you don't find it, add that element to your answer array. You could do this faster with a map as well.

```
for(int i: array1){
    boolean found = false;
    for(int j: array2){
       if(i==j){
          found = true;
       }
    }
    if(!found){
       returnArray.add(i);
    }
}
```